# how to create express js MVC directory structure after installing

Tags: node.js, express

I have an installed node.js + express 4 project. 
I wish to create the structure of directories when created using Express application generator (routes,views etc.)

How can I do this without having to recreate the project?

Answer (score 0):

use [EXPRESS GENERATOR](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-generator) , I can easily generate my routes and create controller ,

Comment: but this creates a new project directory.. I wish to achieve that without*** deleting the current directory

Comment: yes it is restful framework. you can add your code into this project like .. make route into route directory .. create model and controller folder start your work